# R8 stripping out Kotlin companion object needed for reflection

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, proguard, android-r8

I have a class with a companion object which implements a factory interface.

```kotlin
class GoalInspectorData(
    ...
) {

    companion object : DataClassFactory<GoalInspectorData> {

        override fun fromV8Object(v8Object: V8Object): GoalInspectorData {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I have some code which examines this class at runtime using reflection to see if the class provides a factory method. It does this by checking to see if the class has a companion object (`companionObjectInstance`) and, if so, if that companion object implements the factory interface.

```kotlin
internal inline fun <reified T> convert(obj: Any): T {

    val companionObject = T::class.companionObjectInstance

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return when {
        T::class in builtInClasses -> obj as T
        companionObject as? DataClassFactory<T> != null -> companionObject.fromV8Object(obj as V8Object)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("No converter for type ${T::class}")
    }
}
```

This all works fine in a debug build.

It fails in a release build with R8 enabled (`minifyEnabled true` in **build.gradle**). It fails because `companionObjectInstance` returns `null`.

I'm using the *don't optimize* Proguard config:

```groovy
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

and in my own **proguard-rules.pro** I've added just about every `-keep` rule I can imagine in an attempt to retain this companion object, and added `@Keep` annotations to everything, but nothing works. R8 is determined to strip it out.

For example:

```
-keep class my.package.** {
    *;
}
-keep interface my.package.** {
    *;
}

-if class **$Companion extends **
-keep class <2>
-if class **$Companion implements **
-keep class <2>
```

Are there any other `-keep` rules or configuration options which would instruct R8 to retain this companion object?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `@Keep` annotation?

Comment: @RobCo yes, makes no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the keep rule

```
-keep class my.package.** {
    *;
}
```

should be sufficient to keep all the classes - including companion classes in your program. You should not need the `-dontoptimize` flag, so using the configuration `proguard-android-optimize.txt` should be fine.

However, as you use Kotlin reflection you probably also need to keep the annotation class `kotlin.Metadata` and runtime visible annotations with these rules:

```
-keep @interface kotlin.Metadata {
  *;
}
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
```

If that does still not work could you please file an [R8 issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938)? If you can include a simple reproduction that would be great.